# Tomcat/Java - Multiple contexts with one WAR

Tags: java, tomcat

Is it possible to have multiple contexts using the same WAR? For instance, we would like to be able to access

`someserver.com/root1`

`someserver.com/root2`

and have it all be handled by the same WAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least couple of ways I could think of to do that (but I have not tried):

1. Add url rewrite rules to the http server to forward all requests to
   root2 to root1
2. Put war file some please on the server (not webapp
   directory, you probably will have to unpack it) and have 2 config files in
   conf\Catalina\localhost root1.xml and root2.xml which point to the same
   location on the disk.

I think first one would be cleaner as I am not sure if the second way is going to work at all and what is the behavior going to be when you restart apps, etc.